# How to register invoice payment

Tags: openerp-7

When I choose the method of payment the amount is reset to 0 and if I confirm the payment of the invoice the state does not change (open to paid) and there is no error message. I can't set any invoice to paid.

I checked all customers and they are well configured, because I did not rewrite python code so I think the problem is not with the models.

Installed modules:

```
base
crm
sale
account
account_voucher
account_followup
account_management

[and all dependances]
```

Please  can someone help me to understand the problem?

**EDIT**
Only invoices created from orders cannot be  paid.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Why did you delete my answer?